# Will using a relay for triggering remote send interfering signals?

Tags: rf, relay, raspberry-pi, surface-mount, interference

So I have a remote control with a SMD button I want to trigger. To do so, I need to bridge horizontally a pair of the pins, as shown in blue:

[image: A SMD button]

However, when testing this, I connected a long (10cm) cable. I had my headphones plugged in to the computer, and I heard weird high-pitched sound for as long as the pins were connected. The noise was not audible when I disconnected the headphones from the computer, or when taking the headphones out. The noise is not present when pressing the button usually with the headphones connected. What was this sound?

My question is: will I create interference or maybe change the tuning of the device if I use such a long cable to bridge the pins? I'm using a Raspberry Pi and a relay to trigger this button. The PCB remote board takes a 12V input while the Raspberry Pi is a 5V board, would using a transistor be safe and work better in terms of the interference? I'm new to electronics and would like to use the easiest, but most importantly the safest option.

Comment: If it bothers you, try twisting together the wires in the cable, so they loop around each other (many times) (Like a DNA helix shape)

Comment: Also headphones seem to be quite sensitive at picking up high-frequency signals in prototype circuits! It's not likely to mess with your neighbour's TV, so don't worry about that.

Comment: It would be better to use an optoisolator, mounted close to the remote’s button, maybe even in place of it. You could get rid of the relay too.